# how to efficiently do a recursive loop with calculations in a big dataframe using pandas or numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop

I have a 4.5 million row dataframe, that I want to do a simple calculation, that basically goes to the same `KEY` in the previous row and if it meets some conditions, it does the a sum with the entrance `[i]` and `[i-1]` and if not it jumps the sum.

I was able to create something that works fine for what I want, and I am getting the expected results, but it takes to much time, and it calls a `SettingWithCopyWarning` that can be ignore if I turn down the warnings.

So I am reaching out to see if it exist a better way to do this, that is less time consuming for the machine.

my code:

```
df_pivot.sort_values(['key_aux', 'Date'], ascending=[True, True], inplace=True)

df_pivot['YTD_v2'] = 0

for i in range(0, len(df_pivot)):
    df_pivot['YTD_v2'].iloc[i] = np.where((df_pivot['key_aux'].iloc[i]==df_pivot['key_aux'].iloc[i-1]) & (df_pivot['Month'].iloc[i] != 1), 
                                          df_pivot['YTD_v2'].iloc[i-1]+df_pivot['Value'].iloc[i], 
                                          df_pivot['Value'].iloc[i])

<timed exec>:2: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
CPU times: total: 13min 30s
Wall time: 13min 37s
```

As you can see for my loop to work I need to sort the columns `key_aux` and `Date` so that he does what I am expecting.

I do believe it might exist a much better way to do this. I also did this with an standard `if else` loop instead of the `np.where` but was 30 sec more time consuming.

Comment: I would copy the n-1 key to the n-th row. Then it should be simple  to vectorize the calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing sample data and expected output it's hard to be certain, but I think what you're looking for is [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html). Note I'm presuming you have a `Year` column in your dataframe, if not, given that you have a `Date` column it shouldn't be hard to generate one:

```py
df_pivot['YTD_v2'] = df_pivot.groupby(['key_aux', 'Year'])['Value'].cumsum()
```

Comment: It worked wonders. Passed from almost 14 minutes to 1.47 seconds!!! Didn't knew about the command .cumsum() really usefull!

Comment: @PedroGomes great to hear. I'm glad I could help.